# Opening Data Source Explorer from Eclipse 4.3.0

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

How to open Data Source Explorer from Eclipse 4.3.0? I want to use MySQL database from my Java code in Eclipse. To make the connection, I probably need to use Data Source Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `Window > Show View > Other... > Data Management > Data Source Explorer`

You need to have the `Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK` installed.